# How to connect to remote PostgreSQL server with ssh tunnel through C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, ssh, ado.net

I try to connect to remote PostgreSQL server  i have `Host name`,`User Name` `Password` for connecting to database besides i have ssh parameters `SSH host name`,`SSH port`,`SSH user` name and `SSH password`.
I tried to connect to Database by using `Npgsql`
with following code

```
 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=Host name;User Id=User Name;Password=XXXX;Database=XXXX;Port=5432"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select cplid from couple_fixed_extdata where col_10='151902' and col_2='197119';", conn))
                {
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        List<int> couples = new List<int>();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            couples.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

But i get mistake `no pg_hba.conf entry for host XXXX, user XXXX, database XXXX, SSL off`

Comment: That has nothing to do with C# or C# driver for postgres. Your configuration are not proper. Can you connect to your server manually?

Comment: yes,i can connect throw SQL Manager.

Comment: And second quastion should i enter ssh parameters or connection parameters in connectionstring?

Comment: No, you don't need them in your connection string I believe.

Comment: So can i connect to server by using connection parameters only,through c# code?

Comment: Yes you can. Give a try and see